# django play/download mp3 file

Tags: python, django, vs-web-site-project

i am making a website with a list of mp3 files and i want a detail view.
the problem is django cannot find the mp3 file.
it shows up in the source code and the audio bar shows up so i can play/pause adjust volume etc
in download.html i use {{ object.file.url }} in a h1 tag, the url is correct but django gives me a 404 error in the console.
i want the url to be http://example.com/download/(id)
then the download.html shows and they can play the mp3 file or download it.

download.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Download</title>
</head>
<body>
<audio controls>
    <source src="{{ object.file.url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support audio
</audio>
<h1>{{ object.file.url }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, reverse
from .models import Song


def index_view(request):
    queryset = Song.objects.all()
    context = {
        'list': queryset
    }

    return render(request, 'index.html', context)


def download_view(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Song, id=id)

    context = {
        'object': obj,
    }

    return render(request, 'download.html', context)
```

setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'pages',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'music.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'music.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = ''
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

from pages.views import index_view, download_view

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', index_view),
    path('download/<int:id>', download_view)
]
urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Song(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=122, blank=True, null=True, default="No Title")
    by = models.CharField(max_length=122, blank=True, null=True)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="media")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: What is the error Django is returning? Please make sure to attach the logs so that we can better help you.

Comment: its not django that returning the error its the web browser giving a 404 error
GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/media/yesy.mp3 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Does the URL provided in the 404 error in the terminal match the expected URL the server ought to be returning for the file? In other words, is it the full path to the .mp3?

Comment: the .mp3 file is located under the base directory then /media/media/yesy.mp3 so yes

Comment: @Felipe you got anything? no luck here...

Comment: Sorry, had to run some errands. I see you solved your own issue -- good stuff. I figured it had something to do with the URL path :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED

setting.py
this saves the uploaded files to the static folder

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static', 'media')
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
```

download.html
put /static in the begin to go to /static then file path.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Download</title>
</head>
<body>
<audio controls>
    <source src="/static{{ object.file.url }}" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support audio
</audio>
<h1>{{ object.file.url }}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could also hard code the url to find the specific audio file and then fetch the download url for the download but **every** time creating any django project that uses static file make sure to first specify the static folder or just use the **django** template and **static** files management convention.